# Reading output from terminal using subprocess.run

Tags: python, io, subprocess

I'm writing a python string to parse a value from a JSON file, run a tool called [Googler](https://github.com/jarun/googler) with a couple of arguments including the value from the JSON file, and then save the output of the tool to a file (CSV preferred, but that's for another day).

So far the code is:

```
import json
import os
import subprocess
import time

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    test = (json_data["search_term1"]["apparel"]["biba"])

#os.system("googler -N -t d1 "+test)  shows the output, but can't write to a file.

result= subprocess.run(["googler", "-N","-t","d1",test], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

When I run the above script, nothing happens, the terminal just sits blank until I send a keyboard interrupt and then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 12, in <module>
    result= subprocess.run(["googler", "-N","-t","d1",test], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 695, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1059, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I tried replacing the `test` variable with a string, same error. The same line works on something like `"ls", "-l", "/dev/null"`.

How do I extract the output of this tool and write it to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `googler` command works in interactive mode. It never exits, so your program is stuck.

You want googler to run the search, print the output and then exit.

From the docs, I think `--np` (or `--noprompt`) is the right parameter for that. I didn't test.

```
result = subprocess.run(["googler", "-N", "-t", "d1", "--np", test], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

Comment: Yes, it did solve my problem. I changed the code to use Popen instead of run  as I needed to use the kill() function. Anyways, any idea on how to write this to a file now?

Comment: Great, you may accept/upvote the answer then. Writing to file is another question. It should be textbook example. Please ask a new question if you can't sort it out with the docs.